# Android Geolocation unable to get your location error in simulator

Tags: android-emulator, geolocation, titanium-mobile

I tried following code for finding out location of user in titanium android

```
application.Ti.App.GeoApp = {};
Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Titanium.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "testing";
Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;
if( Titanium.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled === false ) {
    Ti.API.debug('Your device has GPS turned off. Please turn it on.');
}
function updatePosition(e) {
    if( ! e.success || e.error ) {
    alert("Unable to get your location.");
    Ti.API.debug(JSON.stringify(e));
    Ti.API.debug(e);
    return;
    }
    Ti.App.fireEvent("app:got.location", {
    "coords" : e.coords
    });
};

Ti.App.addEventListener("app:got.location", function(d) {
    Ti.App.GeoApp.f_lng = d.longitude;
    Ti.App.GeoApp.f_lat = d.latitude;
    Ti.API.debug(JSON.stringify(d));
    Ti.Geolocation.removeEventListener('location', updatePosition);

    alert(JSON.stringify(d));
});
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition( updatePosition );    
Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener( 'location', updatePosition );
```

after running this code it gives alert **Unable to get your location.**in android simulator
What thing which I am missing? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to connect using telnet to your emulator and "set the location". Each time you set the location you will get an event.

`
telnet localhost 5554 (take in consideration that sometimes the port is different - you can see it in the window title bar).

Trying 127.0.0.1...

Connected to localhost.

Escape character is '^]'.

Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands

OK

geo fix 15.4548 12.4548 (parameters are longitude, latitude in degrees)

OK

quit
`

Enjoy